# ajax not working in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

i'm using jsf and ajax. I want to catch inputText change, and print text out to console. Here is xhtml file:

```
<h:form>
      <h:inputText id="name" name="string" value="#{class.string}" >
         <f:ajax listener="#{class.printString}" event="valueChange" execute="name"/>
      </h:inputText>

   </h:form>
```

and here managedBean, "printString" function

```
public void printString(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Comment: Andy, next time when you ask a question, elaborate "not working" in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective. There are at least two red herrings in the code which you left unmentioned. Reading JS console and server log as instructed in the duplicate should already give clues. See further also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for guidelines.

Comment: @BalusC Always a pleasure to get corrected by you ;)

Comment: @BalusC thank you so much)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h:inputText id="name" name="string" value="#{class.string}" >
  <f:ajax listener="#{class.printString}" event="keyup" execute="name"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Also change `searchString` to `string` in backing method. Because `h:inputText` have value for `string`

```
public void printString(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        System.out.println(searchString);
    }
```

**MORE**

See [official](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkace.html#gkhvt)

Comment: You forgot to explain why OP's approach didn't work.